# Xpath to find duplicate node values

Tags: xml, xpath

I have following xml file:

```
<Dictionary>
   <words>
       <word>AM</word>       
   </words>
   <words>
       <word>AN</word>
   </words>
   <words>
       <word>AN</word>
   </words>
</Dictionary>
```

I need xpath to find duplicate word nodes like in above "AN" is duplicate. I tried following from web search but it did not work:

```
/*/*[index-of(/*/*/word(), word())[2]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select word that exists the same word  before

```
/Dictionary/words/word[.= ../preceding-sibling::words/word]
```

Answer (score 3):

With `following` axis:

```
//words/word[. = ./following::word]
```

https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#axes